# css giving two outputs in drupal6.20?

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I am using bluemarine theme for my site and I added a css in style.css
as follows

```
#navlist li a {  
/* GP - this will make the li tag take a 30px padding left and right*/  
padding:3px 25px 3px 25px;
font-family: Arial Narrow;
}
```

One output (wrong) is as follows

[image: wrong output]

Other output (right) is like this

[image: right outout]

Please help me to find the correct way to correct this issue.

Also the same is giving different output in IE and firefox ? How can I fix this please help ?

**Font showing different in - Firefox is either not taking from style.css or should I have to specify somewhere else ?**

This happens because of the text resize option of browser . How can I fix this ?

Comment: Best i can say right at this moment is. Get firebug and see whats the difference with these two ( if youre able to create both scenarios ) and then get rid of whatever is messing up with it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are getting a left pad from your `#navlist li a` class that is adding on top of another pad left (perhaps `#navlist` itself?). Look closely at your classes, inheriting back through all of the parents, and see if that might be the case. Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature is excellent for debugging issues like this.

Comment: I am checking on it but still not found the problem in css ? Also one more thing I would like to ask.. that is in firefox the font showing as Times New Roman while in IE it is Arial Narrow which is specified in style.css. How can I make force firefox to use the style sheet ?